# Is there any ways to store firestore datetime stamp with writebath in android studio java?

Tags: java, android

```
                WriteBatch batch = firebaseFirestore.batch();
                DocumentReference doc1 = firebaseFirestore.collection("Order").document();
                batch.set(doc1, ProductList);

                DocumentReference doc2 = firebaseFirestore.collection("user").document(firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid());
                batch.update(doc2, "studentAmount", user.getStudentAmount() - ProductTotalPrice);


                batch.commit().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                        Toast.makeText(ConfirmPaymentActivity.this, "Complete the transaction successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                        Toast.makeText(ConfirmPaymentActivity.this, "Fail to complete the transaction", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });
```

Is there any way to store the date with the DateTime stamp based on the time that the document wrote to the firestore? Now I using the writebatch doc1 to store the data but I unable to add in one more field for the datetime field.........Can anyone help?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

public class ProductList {

```
public FieldValue Timestamp;
public double totalPrice;
public String userId;
public List<String> productList;

public ProductList(double totalPrice, String userId, List list, FieldValue fieldValue) {
    this.totalPrice = totalPrice;
    this.userId = userId;
    this.productList = list;
    this.Timestamp = fieldValue;
}
```

}

```
                List<String> list = Arrays.asList(ScanResulttoArray);
                ProductList = new ProductList(ProductTotalPrice, "I20018673",list,FieldValue.serverTimestamp());
```